# how to read JSON with HTML in Flutter App?

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

Fetching JSON in Flutter App, which contains Nested Json and HTML content is not working.

### Example:

```
 {"off":
  {
    "02":{
      "id":"02"
         },
    "name":"022",
    "type":"Test",
    "phn":[1,2,3,4],
    "org":"wann",
    "email":"cc@gmail.com",
    "description":"AS",
    "html":"<div>ID: 02<br>Name: 022<br>Org: wann<br>Description: AS</div>"
  }
 }
    ####################
 final jsonResponse= json.decode(response.body);
```

Error:
Half content of JSON fetches from API due to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... When I tested to convert from string to Json, it looks good.
Because the data you attached is Map type, I tested with all string.

```
import 'dart:convert' show json;
import 'dart:core';

void main() {
  var data ='''{"off":
  {
    "02":{
      "id":"02"
         },
    "name":"022",
    "type":"Test",
    "phn":[1,2,3,4],
    "org":"wann",
    "email":"cc@gmail.com",
    "description":"AS",
    "html":"<div>ID: 02<br>Name: 022<br>Org: wann<br>Description: AS</div>"
  }
 }''';

  final jsonResponse= json.decode(data);
  print(jsonResponse);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, You are right, but the problem is when I call API through 'await http.post(URL)' and 'json.decode(response.body);' in Flutter App,  it returns half JSON, and the actual JSON content is four times greater than above example.

Comment: The **print** function in Flutter does not print the entire data, if the receiving content is large.